# How i could get the averages from a file saved as a text file

Tags: python

I have to take information from a text file in the form of:

```
Dom : 9
Eathan : 0
Harry : 8
Jack : 7
Jake : 0
James : 1
Jeffin : 1
Louis : 8
Sam : 0
Tom : 3
William : 0
```

I need to take the scores from this text file save them as an `int` (because they're strings) and work out the average and print it.

```python
import random
import operator

def randomCalc():
    ops = {'+':operator.add,
           '-':operator.sub,
           '*':operator.mul,
           '/':operator.truediv}
    num1 = random.randint(0,12)
    num2 = random.randint(1,10)   
    op = random.choice(list(ops.keys()))
    answer = ops.get(op)(num1,num2)
    print('What is {} {} {}?\n'.format(num1, op, num2))
    return answer

def askQuestion():
    answer = randomCalc()
    while True:
      try:
         guess = float(input())#The Answer the user inputs to the question asked
      except ValueError: #When anything but a interger is inputted.
        print ("That is not a valid answer")
        continue #Dosen't print Invalid Code Error
      else:
        break
    return guess == answer

def quiz():
    print('Welcome. This is a 10 question math quiz\n')
    score = 0
    for i in range(10):
        correct = askQuestion()
        if correct:
            score += 1
            print('Correct!\n')
        else:
            print('Incorrect!\n')
    print ("\nYour score was {}/10 Well done".format(score))
    print ("\nWhat is your name")
    name = str(input())
    class_name = input("\nWhich class do you wish to input results for? ")
    class_name = class_name + ".dat"    #adds '.txt' to the end of the file so it can be used to create a file under the name a user specifies

    file = open(class_name, "a")   #opens the file in 'append' mode so you don't delete all the information
    name = (name)
    file.write(str(name + " : " )) #writes the information to the file
    file.write(str(score))
    file.write('\n')
    file.close()
    return score

quiz()

viewscore_alpha = str(input("\nWould you like to view the score`s of players alphabeticaly: Yes or No"))
if viewscore_alpha == "yes".lower():
    class_name = input("\nWhich class do you wish to View results for? ")
    class_name = class_name + ".dat"
    with open(class_name) as file: #  use with to open files as it closes them automatically
        file.seek(0) # go back to start  of file
        for line in f: # print each name
            print(line)
        file.seek(0) # go back to start again
        lines = sorted(file.readlines()) # sort the names
        with open(class_name, "w") as file_save:  # write names in sorted order
            for line in lines: 
                file_save.write(line)
        file.close()
        file_save.close90
elif viewscore_average == "no".lower() :
    viewscore_average = str(input("\nWould you like to view the score`s of classes avrages?: Yes or No"))
    if viewscore_average == "yes".lower():
        chars = set("0123456789")


    else:
        viewscore_higest = str(input("\nWould you like to view the score`s of players alphabeticaly: Yes or No"))
        if viewscore_higest == "yes".lower():
```

That is all I have and I'm stuck.

Comment: Please post the rest of the code as we can't guess what you've done.

Comment: Yes, please post the code.  Otherwise, it looks like you're asking us to write the code for you, which is not allowed here.

Also, show the output you *do* get -- at least a blocking syntax error.  Comments will also help, so we know what you designed (what you're *trying* to do).

Comment: For a start, you should try moving the `lower()` function to your variable, e.g. `viewscore_average.lower()`.

Comment: I'm going to assume that you have a plain text file, because [`.dat`](http://pc.net/extensions/file/dat) isn't a well defined filetype.

Comment: Here's a brief approach:
(1) For each line:
(a) split on the colon
(b) grab the second item (that's the score)
(c) convert to integer
(d) add to a running sum  (such as total += score_integer)

(2) Divide the sum by the quantity of scores ...
... either count them as you go, or take the number of lines in the file.

Comment: I understand that But is there need to convert to int()

Comment: Also, look up the Python len, sum, and avg functions; they may well shorten your work load.

Comment: I don't see what that code has to do with the question. It seems to do completely different things, such as ask the user questions and perform calculations. Post the relevant code only, and clarify what you have accomplished and where you are having trouble.

Comment: All my code is working i just cant seem to comprehend what to do to work out the average.

Comment: I have to complete a checklist of stuff to do. The code is meant to run a 10 question quiz it shows the score and then the player/ user should be able to view the Names and scores of players in three different ways i have done one of the ways i need to do the others but i am a little confused 1) View in alphabetical order (of Names) 2) view with Highest score First down to lowest  and 3) to view the average score of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break it down into logical steps.

1. open the file (and initialize a few variables we'll use later)

   ```
   running_total = 0
   num_scores = 0
   with open("path/to/file.txt") as scoresfile:
   ```
2. read each line

   ```
       for line in scoresfile:
   ```
3. split each line on the colon

   ```
           splitline = line.split(":")
   ```
4. convert the score to an int

   ```
           score = int(splitline[1])  # splitline[1] is the score
   ```
5. add the score to the running total

   ```
           running_total += score
   ```
6. increment the number of lines we've read to divide for an average

   ```
           num_scores += 1
   ```
7. let the `for` loop finish, then do your math to find the average

   ```
   average = running_total / num_scores
   ```

You can combine a few of these steps through the magic of list comprehension to come up with something a bit more concise, that looks like:

```
with open('path/to/file.txt') as scoresfile:
    scores = [int(score) for line in scoresfile for 
              _, score in line.split(":")]
average = sum(scores)/len(scores)
```

Comment: There is too many values to unpack (expected 2) when you say        scores = [int(score) for line in scoresfile for 
              _, score in line.split(":")]

Comment: @BrianStrugnell what do you think that error message might mean?

Comment: It may mean that there is a problem with running 2 different for loops in a continuous sequence i am not 100% sure could you explain @Adam Smith

Comment: Whenever you're getting an error that's talking about "unpacking", you should look at tuple unpacking. In this case the `for _, score in line.split(":")`. Tuple unpacking basically "skips" a step so instead of doing `splitline = line.split(":"); score = splitline[1]`, you can do `name, score = line.split(":")`. However it's getting too many values to unpack into two variables! Essentially there's some line where `len(line.split(":")) > 2`

Comment: (I use `_, score` by convention. The `_` variable name isn't special in any way, but is an easy way to demonstrate that you never need to access this value -- you're only saving it because syntax requires you to. Had I done `name, score = line.split(":")`, it wouldn't be obvious that we never use the `name` anywhere.)

Comment: I am still not 100%. I don't know the idea of separating the code using a _, and how to over come the problem. i have not been doing python that long. Sorry

Comment: @BrianStrugnell then don't use that method. Never ever ever use code that you don't understand. If you're not to the point that you can grok that bit of code, hack your way around it. How else can you get the second element in the list returned by `line.split(":")`?

Comment: Please just tell me the code and explain it that way i find i learn easier that way. Please

Comment: @BrianStrugnell with all due respect, it doesn't sound like you've learned very much at all....